# Sock file is not creating in my django project with gunicorn

Tags: django, linux, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my django project properly with gunicorn. But i'm unable to do that. I'm doing the following process again and again...

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/dotescrow_main
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/dotescrow_main/dotescrow_env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/dotescro>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then i run following commands in a sequence.

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

it returns :

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-03-13 22:21:36 UTC; 15min ago
   Main PID: 563946 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 2372)
     Memory: 100.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─563946 /home/ubuntu/dotescrow_main/dotescrow_env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/dotescrow_main/dotescrow_env/bin/gunicorn>
```

after that when i check sock like in myproject by

```
ls /home/ubuntu/dotescrow_main
```

I dont get any sock file there.

after that when i run     `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn` i get following output:

```
Jan 26 18:30:55 ip-172-31-11-244 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Jan 26 18:30:55 ip-172-31-11-244 systemd[92397]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Jan 26 18:30:55 ip-172-31-11-244 systemd[92397]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/ubuntu/dotescrow/myprojecte>
Jan 26 18:30:55 ip-172-31-11-244 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Jan 26 18:30:55 ip-172-31-11-244 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: refer:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: i'm already following that tutorial.

Comment: try create sock file /run